# How to use multiple data providers in a single describe in protractor

Tags: protractor

I want to write multiple test cases using data-provider in a single 'describe' class how to define it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write the 'describe' block using multiple 'it' blocks with separate 'data-provider' for each as below:

```
describe('Test Suite', function () {

       function dataProvider1()
       {
           //definition of dataprovider 1
       }
       using(dataProvider1, function(data){
            it( "test case 1", function(){
                //testcase definition
            })
       })


       function dataProvider2()
       {
           //definition of dataprovider 2
       }
       using(dataProvider2, function(data){
            it( "test case 2", function(){
                //testcase definition
            })
       })

});
```